# How to keep my topics printing consecutively, without an empty page after each topic

Tags: page-break, dita, dita-ot

DITA 3.6
Oxygen XML Editor 23.1

The "DITA for Print" book nor any other source, so far, has helped me produce a pdf where the topics are consecutive rather than having a blank page after them. To each topicref in the ditamap, I added outputclass="page-break-avoid". To each topic element in each file, I added outputclass="page-break-avoid".

Should I add something in an xsl file? Can you point me to the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The blank page is generated from the definition `fo:page-sequence/@force-page-number` property.

To change not to generate blank-page, you can override `org.dita.pdf2/cfg/fo/attrs/commons-attr.xsl`.

```xml
    <xsl:attribute-set name="__force__page__count">
        <xsl:attribute name="force-page-count">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="/*[contains(@class, ' bookmap/bookmap ')]">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'even'"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'auto'"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>
```

Change the value `even` to `auto` will satisfy your needs.

### Steps to customize

I'm not familiar with PDF2 plug-in. So this may not the standard way. But I could customize it by following steps.

1. Make customization XSL file

[DITA-OT]/plugins/org.dita.pdf2/Customization/fo/attrs/commons-attr.xsl

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    xmlns:rx="http://www.renderx.com/XSL/Extensions"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:attribute-set name="__force__page__count">
        <xsl:attribute name="force-page-count">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="/*[contains(@class, ' bookmap/bookmap ')]">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'auto'"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'auto'"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

2. Include it into [DITA-OT]/plugins/org.dita.pdf2/Customization/fo/attrs/custom.xsl

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:include href="commons-attr.xsl"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

3. Customize [DITA-OT]/plugins/org.dita.pdf2/Customization/catalog.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog" prefer="system">
  <!-- Custom attributes entry -->
  <uri name="cfg:fo/attrs/custom.xsl" uri="fo/attrs/custom.xsl"/>
</catalog>
```

4. Specify `customization.dir` property with `[DITA-OT]\plugins\org.dita.pdf2\Customization` in Oxygen transformation scenario.

[image: Oxygen transformation scenario]

5. Apply transformation scenario from Oxygen.
6. I've got the following `temp/topic.fo`. The `fo:page-sequence/@force-page-count` became `auto` and in the result PDF, the redundant blank pages are removed.

[image: temp/topic.fo comparison]

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. It's not working however. I saved commons-attr.xsl to the Customization/fo/attrs location. I'm in Oxygen XML Editor 23.1, DITA 3.3.

Comment: @n3v3r8g81n I've added the sample customization steps. I'm also working with the newest Oxygen XML Editor 23.1.

Comment: Perfect. thank you for the additional steps. you are a good writer. unfortunately, still fails. I'm also working Dita for Print book. See https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WlhNj40JHWXH1yIOLa4Qn9SxgSyJcKYp/view?usp=drivesdk. And may I express my gratitude by sending a little $?

Comment: @n3v3r8g81n If you still fails for getting the desired result, give me anything you have noticed in your customization. I am always ready to reproduce your operating steps because you are using same Oxygen version.

Comment: @n3v3r8g81n Your customization seems to be right. If possible, could you send me `temp/topic.fo` file archive in temporary folder?